# Snapshoting a workspace in WM: layout and programs which are opened

Tags: awesome-wm, i3, x-dwm

I was wondering if it was possible to snapshot a workspace, i.e. save state not only of the layout but also of the windows which were opened.

- Why do I need this?
- Because I switch between different workflows. I may program for a while and then I may want to switch to a different activity, then switch back again to programming. On the average I have up to 7 windows on my workspace. 
  I need to save RAM for (freeze and lag)-less workflow.
  I want to be able to close workspace 1, switch to another - workspace 2, then restore workspace 1 from the point when I had left it.

This should be totally manual, so I still can work on multiple workspaces. I have to control whether I want to close and restore previous workspace session.
When I restore the workspace, it should be just like I had left it, given that I hadn't changed the files or deleted programs that were opened.

1. Can this be done at all or at least some part of it with any WM?
2. Is this a stupid idea?
3. Does not running a graphical UI saves me RAM (how much)? - so maybe the windows should not be killed when closed, but rather run in the background (daemon), like in Tmux.

Earlier I tried i3 and Awesome(briefly). The biggest struggle was the toolbar, manual set up of volume, brightness, language switching control and proper fonts (on Arch Linux), I didn't fully succeed in setting my environment(I skimmed through wikis) so I fled.

Is it easier to set up Awesome in this respect?
Currently I use Cinnamon+Debian, and I'm almost happy with it.
I'd like to use touchpad less and therefore ask for advice.
I'll try to set WM up on VM first for painless transition.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar before in i3-wm. I created a keybind to a bash script in my path that opens four terminator terminals on an empty screen. It uses the i3 command i3-msg to tell the window manager how the behavior of the next window opened will change. Here is my script:

```
terminator          # opens terminal, change to the terminal that you use
i3-msg split h      # tells i3 that the next window should split screen vertically
terminator          # opens terminal
i3-msg split v      # tells i3 that next window should split current one horizontally
terminator          # opens terminal
i3-msg focus left   # Changes selected window to the left one
i3-msg split v      # tells i3 that the next window should split screen vertically
terminator
```

You should be able to take the i3-msg command and use it to control how windows of your applications open.

This is a quick, hacky solution, but it does work.

I hope this was able to help!

phylo